# jquery - Change CSS based on scroll position

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am designing and developing a template similar to [duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/course/eo/en/Learn-Esperanto-Online)
And now I'm asking you to help me change the appearance of the h1 tag and style the topbar
The code I wrote for this topic is as follows, but it's not a recipe and does not work well with the sample website.

```
setInterval(function() {
                var height = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (height >= 0 && height < 120) {
                    $('.long-header-label').css('font-size', "34px");
                    $('.btn-start-index').css({
                        'visibility': 'visible',
                        'opacity': '1',
                        'display': 'inline-block'
                    });
                    $('.btn-start-header').css("display","none");
                    $('.cta-container').css({
                        'position':'relative',
                        'display':'block'
                    });
                }
                if (height > 119 && height < 200) {
                    $('.long-header-label').css('font-size', "29.5px");
                    $('.btn-start-index').css({
                        'visibility': 'hidden',
                        'opacity': '0',
                        'display': 'none'
                    });
                    $('.cta-container').css({
                        'position':'relative',
                        'display':'block'
                    });
                    $('.btn-start-header').css({
                    "margin-left": " 10px",
                    "display": " inherit"
                    });

                }
                if (height > 199 && height < 265) {
                    $('.long-header-label').css('font-size', "22px");
                    $('.btn-start-index').css({
                        'visibility': 'hidden',
                        'opacity': '0',
                        'display': 'none'
                    });
                    $('.cta-container').css({
                        'position':'fixed',
                        'display':'none'
                    });
                    $('.btn-start-header').css({
                        "margin-left": " 10px",
                        "display": " inherit"
                    });
                }


        }, 100);
```

Comment: You have not described the desired effect.  What would you like changed based on scroll position? Should it change only at one set position, or based on several positions?  Also, it's nearly impossible to help without the rendered HTML as well.

Comment: Personally I would do this in a `scroll` event handler and use various classes that have associated css style rules. Check both height and current class(es). Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]